# Loopback: How remove internal properties from list

Tags: mongodb, properties, model, internal, loopback

When i ask my db for a embedded Object i become a list. This list is to update. Loopback return a List like this:

```
List [
 { variable: 'string',
   relation: 'string',
   value: 'string',
   id: null } ] }
```

After manipulating this – add or remove – i will rewrite this via updateall to the database. now i have in the database the hiddenPropertys like this:

```
"__cachedRelations" : {
    "__data" : {
        "variable" : "d", 
        "relation" : "r", 
        "value" : "1"
    }, 
    "__dataSource" : null, 
    "__strict" : false, 
    "__persisted" : false, 
    "variable" : "d", 
    "relation" : "r", 
    "value" : "1", 
    "id" : null
}
```

How can i this disable or convert? Thanks a lot for solving this.